# jQuery show/hide rule

Tags: jquery

Basically I am trying to show hide divs and links, but having some trouble. The functionality required is as follows:

- On page load, DIV ID 'additional-languages' is hidden
- User can click the 'Selected Additional Languages' link which will show the 'additional-languages' DIV
- At the point of clicking this link, the link will get hidden
- User can then choose to hide the 'additional-languages' DIV by clicking on the 'hide' link
- At the point of clicking this link, the 'Selected Additional Languages' link will re-appear

Here is what I have done so far:

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="native_language">Select</label>
    <select name="native_language" id="native_language">
      <option value="">Any</option>
      <option value="1">English</option>
    </select>

    <a class="show-additional-link" href="#">Select Additional Languages</a>
</div>

<div id="additional-languages" style="display: none;">
    <a class="hide-additional-link" href="#">[hide]</a>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- additional language checkboxes -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.show-additional-link').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
});
```

The first part is working for me, but I'm struggling on getting the second part to work, i.e. the functionality for the 'hide-additional-link'. I have tried this:

```
$('.hide-additional-link').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
    $(this).parent().prev('.show-additional-link').show();
    return false;
});
```

The DIV gets hidden but the 'show-additional-link' does not get shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(this).prev('.show-additional-link').show();
```

to this:

```
$(this).parent().prev("div.row").find('.show-additional-link').show();
```

`.prev` will target, strictly, the immediately previous sibling. Your `.show-additional-link` button is a child of the previous div, so basically you need to go up one level, get the previous div, and find the `.show-additional-link` descendant.

Comment: Sorted. I wasn't aware of this 'find()' function! Cheers.

Comment: How come something like this doesn't work: `$(this).parent().prev('.row > .show-additional-link').show();`

Comment: Because there can be no previous sibling element which is a descendant of something else, so `.prev('.row > .show-additional-link')` *cannot* return anything. The selector it accepts is a filter. If I say `.prev('.foo')` then it will return the previous sibling only *if* it has the `.foo` class. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd just go with `$(".show-additional-link")` for readability and extensibility.  You want it to be easy for UI designers to move pieces of HTML around the page without having to touch javascript code.

If there are multiple `.show-additional-link`s on the page, start giving them IDs

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.show-additional-link').show();
```

Because `.show-additional-link` is *inside* the prev element.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hide-additional-link').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
    $(this).parents('#additional-languages').prev('.row').find('.show-additional-link').show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for karim79's answer: Your hide-additional-link function is looking in the #additional-languages context for the previous sibling item with class 'show-additional-link'. It needs to be looking in .row.